# searching for keywords with symbols in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

i indexed my database to lucene for full text search. everything works fine when searching for keywords which has no symbols but whenever i search for keywords having slashes, decimals, etc. (i.e. 1/4, 1.234, 1-1/4") lucene returns no search results. what is the best way to do in indexing symbols?

Comment: What analyzer are you using? Are those symbols in text fields or separate fields?

Comment: @Thomas is correct, you are likely using StandardAnalyzer which strips  out most punctuation and symbols. You could pass a custom stopwords list or write a custom analyzer to suit your needs.

Comment: i use standardanalyzer. the symbols are on the same field. if standardanalyzer strips out symbols, what will be the best analyzer to use?

Comment: i have an idea but i am not sure if it will work. i am planning to modify the stop words of standardanalyzer by disable all stop words except for spaces. i tried whitespaceanalyzer for my code but it didnt work. how will i implement it?

Answer (score 3):

Lucene has a couple of characters that should be escaped:

> The characters that need to be escaped are: + - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

Comment: Add to that the special keywords (in uppercase) AND, OR and NOT.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at Regular Expression. It should allow you to see if a string contains that character, where it is, and will allow you to replace it.

[JavaDocs on Regular Expressions Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, newer versions of Lucene already have a convenience method for escaping the said characters in the form of a static method called [escape(String s)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29) in QueryParser.

From the docs:

```
public static String escape(String s)

    Returns a String where those characters that QueryParser expects to be escaped are escaped by a preceding \.
```